# Can a battlemaster use Maneuvering Attack to prevent two creatures from opportunity attacking one ally?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, battle-master

> **Maneuvering Attack.** When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can expend one superiority die to maneuver one of your comrades into a more advantageous position. You add the superiority die to the attack's damage roll, and you choose a friendly creature who can see or hear you. That creature can use its reaction to move up to half its speed without provoking opportunity attacks from the target of your attack.

If an ally is within two enemies' reaches, and the battlemaster has extra attack, hits and uses the maneuver on both enemies, and if the ally only uses the movement reaction when the second creature is hit, would that ally still take opportunity attacks from the first one?

Answer (score 10):

### *Target of your attack* is a clear definition

The maneuver is contingent on hitting a creature and when you do you can have an ally move without provoking opportunity attacks. The expression *target of your attack* clearly references the same attack that made using the maeneuver possible in the first place. It does not say something like the friendly creature does not provoke opportunity attacks from the target of your attack **for the rest of your turn**, which indicates that it is a one-time opportunity, avoiding opportunity attacks from the single target and only during the movement on the reaction.

**In summary, at the time the maneuver takes place, only one creature can be the target of the relevant attack.**

This is also consistent with the flavor of the maneuver which allows you to distract or hamper the enemy so your ally can get away: You lock eyes with your ally, hit the opponent and your ally slips away.